# Load WooCommerce data on demand and show it in a DataGrid by Syncfusion

Tags: node.js, reactjs, woocommerce, syncfusion, woocommerce-rest-api

I need to load all the products in my nodeJS application with WooCommerce Rest Api. I use the [WooCommerce REST API - JavaScript Library](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api-js-lib) and the [Syncfusion Grid Component](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/grid/getting-started/). Because I can't load all data at once, I wanted to use the *Load data on demand* like [this](https://www.syncfusion.com/react-components/react-data-grid/paging), but I can't find any documentation or examples on this.

I have something like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { GridComponent, ColumnsDirective, ColumnDirective, Resize, Sort, ContextMenu, Filter, Page, ExcelExport, PdfExport, Edit, Inject } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-grids';
import WooCommerceRestApi from "@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api";

var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'http://example.com',
  consumerKey: 'ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  consumerSecret: 'cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  wpAPI: true,
  version: 'wc/v1'
});

const WooCommerceProducts = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchOrders();
  }, []);

  let fetchOrders = () => {
    WooCommerce
      .get("products", {
        per_page: 100,
        page: 1
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setProducts(response.data);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => { });
  };

  return (
    <div className='m-2 md:m-10 p-2 md:p-10 bg-white rounded-3xl'>
      <Header category="Page" title="WooCommerce Orders" />
      <GridComponent
        id='gridcomp'
        dataSource={orders}
        allowPaging
        allowSorting>
        <ColumnsDirective>
          <ColumnDirective field='id' />
          <ColumnDirective field='name' />
          <ColumnDirective field='slug' />
          <ColumnDirective field='status' />

          ...

        </ColumnsDirective>
        <Inject services={[Resize, Sort, ContextMenu, Filter, Page, ExcelExport, PdfExport]} />
      </GridComponent>
    </div>
  )
}

export default WooCommerceProducts
```

Please help and thx

Comment: where is your setOrders State defined?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any custom services, I suggest you use the custom-binding feature to bind the data to the grid. I would like to share the behavior of custom-binding in EJ2 Grid.

For every grid action (such as **Filter, Page**, etc.,), I have triggered the dataStateChange event, and, in the event arguments, I have sent the corresponding action details (like **skip, take, filter field, value, sort direction**, etc.,) Based on that, you can perform the action in your service, return the data as a **result**, and **count** objects.

Note: ‘**dataStateChange**’ event is not triggered at the Grid initial render. If you are using a remote service, you need to call your remote service by manually with a pagination query (need to set the **skip value as 0** and take a value based on your **pageSize** of **pageSettings** in Grid. If you are not defined **pageSize** in **pageSettings**, you need to send the default value 12 ) in load event of Grid. Please return the result like as "**{result: […], count: …}**" format to Grid.

‘**dataSourceChanged**’ event is triggered when performing **CRUD** actions in Grid. You can perform the CRUD action in your service using action details from this event, and, you need to call the **endEdit** method to indicate the completion of the save operation.

Custom-binding: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/grid/data-binding/data-binding/#custom-binding

Demo: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/demos/#/material/grid/custom-binding

sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v64sms-wx3hsy?file=index.js